# How can I get Vuze to work in Ubuntu 14.04 32 or 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, vuze

I can not get Vuze to work in Ubuntu 14.04
Vuze opens but that’s all. Search does absolutely nothing and HD network nothing.

I have no problem at all in Linux Mint 16 or 17, Vuze works just fine but not Ubuntu.

I think I'm going crazy so would someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the vuze installation instructions](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Initial_Setup_Guide#Linux) Ubuntu modifies the Vuze files before putting them into their repository.  You might need to download the latest version from Vuze, and compile it yourself.